# Do we need to continue having paid Apple's developer account for keeping the app on App store?

Tags: ios-appstore, developer-program

I got an iOS app made for my experiments from a free lancer. He asked me to subscribe to Apple Developer Program and then using the account he uploaded the app on the app store. I paid $98.99 for the account for annual subscription. Do I need to renew that subscription each year for keeping the app on App store?

Please feel free to ask for clarifications on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to renew your subscription in order to keep the app on the App Store and attract new users. The app will continue to work though for users that have already installed it prior to the subscription expiring.

As per Apple's [web site](https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/):

> If your Apple Developer Program membership expires, your apps will no longer be available for download and you won’t be able to submit new apps or updates. You’ll lose access to prerelease software, Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, and TSIs. However, your apps will still function for users who have already installed or downloaded them, and you will still have access to App Store Connect and free development resources.

Comment: Thanks @jksoegaard, Can I not renew now and then renew two years later can resume from where I left?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "resume where you left"... I'm not fully sure, but I think you can skip a year, renew it, and then publish an update to the app - yes. But you'll loose things like the device list you've added to App Store Connect, etc. - Those things are deleted after 180 days of inactivity.

Comment: You got it right. So, essentially to save thhe cost. I can renew after 179 days of expiry?

Comment: In principle yes, but you wouldn’t be able to sell anything or release updates in that time. You also risk Apple denying your re-subscription  for their own reasons.